# Why 2 variables with the same name don't mess up the code?

Tags: python

I have this simple code in python that calculates the meal + tax + tip:

```
meal = 44.50
tax = 0.0675
tip = 0.15

meal = meal + meal * tax
total = meal + meal * tip

print("%.2f" % total)
```

I would like to know why does the code run without any problems when we clearly have 2 variables with the same name but different value? The variable i'm referring to is "meal" on line 1 and line 5

Would somebody please clarify this for me?

Thanks!

Comment: You can overwrite and reuse variables with no problems in Python. In some other languages you can't redeclare variables.

Comment: You don't have two variables with the same name.  You are re-assigning the variable a new value.

Comment: I'm curious what your background is. There are languages that only allow names to be bound once (or that use different syntax for initial binding and rebinding), but none of the "mainstream" ones work that way. Is this an intuition that you brought from math? If so, you're thinking like an ML or Haskell programmer, which is something you can brag about. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have two variables, the *name* `meal` is the variable, it's the *value* of that variable (the 'pointer' to an integer object, not the integer object itself) that's being overwritten in the second `meal = ...` statement.

So you no longer have access to the first value. As far as that variable name is concerned, you can only access the second one. See this example

```
>>> meal = 5   # first meal variable
>>> id(meal)
30126376

>>> meal = meal + 7  # second meal variable
>>> id(meal)
30126292
```

Note that the "2nd" `meal` variable has a new ID. That is because it is a new `int` that happens to have the same name. The previous variable is no longer accessible.

Comment: Re the wording "You don't have two variables, you no longer have access to the first one" - hmm, conceptually I would same it's the same _variable_ (i.e., name), it's just the object _behind_ it has changed (the value).

Comment: Bear with me, I'll make an edit, you can see if you like it or not.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I really don't like the word "overwritten" in the edited version. It makes it sound like there's some "memory slot" (like a variable in C or C++) that holds an integer, and the contents of that slot have been updated. But of course that's not what's happened; there's a completely separate integer value being created in a brand new memory slot, and the name is just rebound to that new value. (The rest of the answer makes this point, but I think it starts off misleading, and a novice might not notice it's being corrected later.)

Comment: please correct your explanation. this is incorrect to say the previous variable is no longer accesible. try to reassign meal = 5 and id(meal), it may show the previous id which memory has stored into. meal is just a name assigned to an integer object 5, then another integer object was created and pointed to meal

Comment: I've coorected based on the first comment but I think starting to talk about the life of unbound objects is probably getting a little too deep into Python internals. Given the beginner level of the question, I suspect that would bd a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `meal`. Remember that assignments are done last - first the program calculates `meal + meal * tax` as a temporary variable, then redefines `meal` to have the value of that temporary variable. Try printing the value before and after that line as an illustration. The actual execution behind the scenes looks like this:

```
temporary = meal + meal * tax
meal = temporary
#temporary is out of scope at this point
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a value to `meal` a second time (on the line`meal = meal + meal * tax`), the previous value of `44.50` gets overwritten - you have no way to access the value `44.50` anymore. So, there are never two `meal` objects existing at the same time in this particular snippet of code.