# open cv2 image isn't updating on cv2.putText

Tags: python, opencv

I have a typical computer vision project in Python...counting people in a room, but one thing I notice is that when trying to plot in the frame `people` top left in the screenshot below the number is getting garbled some how. Its very "jumpy" as I am still finding a good model so I its like the number keeps updating but the old number stays in the frame... I'm also rendering this through the browser with a Flask App where the video streams ~28 frames per second.

[image]

This is the function I am using to box people in the frame with the white rectangles as well as show the fixed upper left `people` in the frame in black...what is odd is the boxes drawn with cv2.rectangle around the people update quite fast and there isn't any garbled issues in the frame for that all. Any tips appreciated.

```
def postprocess(result, image):

    people = 0
    detections = result.reshape(-1, 7)
    
    for i, detection in enumerate(detections):
        _, image_id, confidence, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = detection
        if confidence > 0.6:

            people += 1
            
            xmin = int(max((xmin * image.shape[1]), 10))
            ymin = int(max((ymin * image.shape[0]), 10))
            xmax = int(min((xmax * image.shape[1]), image.shape[1] - 10))
            ymax = int(min((ymax * image.shape[0]), image.shape[0] - 10))

            conf = round(confidence, 2)
            print(f"conf: {conf:.2f}")
            print((xmin, ymin),(xmax, ymax))

            # For bounding box
            cv2.rectangle(image, (xmin, ymin),
                          (xmax, ymax), (255, 255, 255), 5)

            # For the text background
            # Finds space required
            (w, h), _ = cv2.getTextSize(
                f"{conf:.2f}", cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.7, 1)

            # Prints the text.
            cv2.rectangle(image, (xmin, ymin + h + 5),
                          (xmin + w + 5, ymin), (255, 255, 255), -1)
            cv2.putText(image, f"{conf:.2f}", (xmin, ymin + h),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.7, (0, 0, 0), 3)

        cv2.putText(image, f"People: {people}",
                    (10, 10 + h),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.7, (0, 0, 0), 3)
            

    return image, people
```

Comment: Looks like you are not creating deep copies of your image before drawing the text onto them. See: https://towardsdatascience.com/shallow-deep-copies-stop-making-these-slicing-mistakes-12d02ffa2f7f

Answer (score 0):

Per @stateMachine comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/shallow-deep-copies-stop-making-these-slicing-mistakes-12d02ffa2f7f

I moved the cv2 code that isnt plotting properly to a new function, this part of the original function shown in the question:

```
image = insert_people_count(image,people)
return image, people
```

This new function which seems to create a "deep" copy as defined in the towards data science article:

```
def insert_people_count(image,people):
    cv2.putText(image, f"People: {people}",
        (15, 25),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.1, (0, 0, 0), 2)
    return image
```

I think Python in the background creates copies (deep copies) even with the same name `image = image` these are technically copies of itself with the same name, like Python references two different items not the same [as documented in this old SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416218/why-2-variables-with-the-same-name-dont-mess-up-the-code)